# Почему в браузере Tor разные сайты показывают разные значения моего IP

Tags: ip, tor

Захожу на различные сайты через браузер Tor, которые определяют мой IP-адрес, и каждый из них показывает разный. Из-за чего это происходит.

Comment: Потому что цепочка Tor-узлов для каждого сайта своя собственная и соответственно выходной узел каждый раз разный

Comment: А это можно как то посмотреть или настроить? эту цепочку?

Comment: Посмотреть — в адресной строке в замочке слева, настроить — не знаю

Comment: а почему вы здесь пишете а не в ответе? ну и не только вы

Comment: https://www.torproject.org/ru/about/history/